# CiviContribute form - no send through to payment (PayPal) screen when not logged in to Civi (refresh instead)

Tags: civicontribute, drupal, permissions

We have set up a CiviContribution form which works well when someone uses it when logged in, but unfortunately it doesn't work for someone who is not logged in to Civi. We intend to use the form specifically for people who don't have a Civi login. What happens is that when someone completes their details (contact and amount they want to contribute) and they click 'confirm contribution' the page is refreshed instead of proceeding the confirmation page.

We have contacted PayPal and the issue is not on their side.

We have checked the permissions and have these on:
- CiviCRM: profile create
- CiviCRM: profile edit
- CiviCRM: profile view
- CiviCRM: access all custom data
- CiviContribute: make online contributions

Would anyone have any idea how to fix this?

Many thanks,
Jantine